# Dropwizard V2 endpoints

Tags: java, jackson, swagger, dropwizard

I currently have a Dropwizard application and a complete set of implemented v1 endpoints which were partially generated with Swagger.

In addition to the v1 endpoints, I now want to provide another set of endpoints (v2) which mainly uses similar code but mostly different JSON serialization (using Jackson JsonProperty).  What is the best approach for providing both sets of endpoints?

Currently, the only solution I have thought of is to just completely create a new set of endpoints and utilize common functions between them but I was hoping there'd be a simpler way.

Comment: From a purist perspective, you should not have a v1.1 of those endpoints. If the requests/responses are not backwards compatible with the previous version of the API, then this should be v2. If you are just making changes to the JSON serialization which does not break existing clients (e.g. adding an extra attribute) then there is no need to introduce a new version of the API.

Comment: I've edited to v2 since they are not backwards compatible

Comment: There is nothing in DW specific to managing multiple API versions. You would need to create a new set of endpoints like this example http://maxenglander.com/2013/04/23/basic-restful-api-versioning-in-jersey.html and expose the new resource.